# Autofill Framework disabled in app, but enabled in other apps

Tags: android, autofill, android-autofill-manager

I ran into problems when trying to use Autofill Framework for the login fragment, it does not show the save popup. I placed `android:autofillHints` attribute on both text fields, then I tried `android:importantForAutofill="yes"` on both with the same results, and I also tried to call `AutofillManager.requestAutofill()` and `AutofillManager.commit()` manually.

Next I downloaded an example from [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-AutofillFramework) and installed it, and it worked normally. I used debug to check AutofillManager in both apps and it turned out that `AutofillManager.isEnabled()` produces different results: true in a sample app and false in my app. In both cases I checked the first line of `onCreate()` in a first activity of an app, which in both cases does not contain fields to be filled.

That's why I think a problem is not in the code or layout files, but rather in the gradle or manifest files, but I could not find any difference in those that could have affected the Autofill Framework. I do not think that framework also has configuration values. I checked targetSdk and minSdk, but that's not it

What else should I check?

Comment: @g-ciardini, I would appreciate if you checked the edits you make, since you managed to completely butcher attribute names, bracket placing, placed a few unnecesary spaces, and removed link to an example

Comment: You have no guarantee that your app will trigger a save popup, because that  depends on the autofill service implementation.
If you want to make sure you're using the right `autofillHints`, I'd suggesting using the `Basic Autofill Service` from the (official samples)[https://github.com/googlesamples/android-AutofillFramework].

Comment: You could also use the `Heuristics Autofill Service` (soon to be renamed `Debug Autofill Service`) if the service doesn't work - this one tries to autofill everything, which is useful for debugging.

Comment: Finally, you usually don't need to call `AutofillManager.requestAutofill()` or `AutofillManager.commit()`, these are meant for people developing custom views (for example, `requestAutofill()` is called by `EditText` when the user long-press a view and select AUTOFILL in the overflow menu), although `AutofillManager.commit()` could be used to indicate your workflow is done (for example, if you're using fragments to replace the screen after the user tapped "Login").

Answer (score 1):

`AutofillManager.isEnabled()` should not produce different results on your app or the sample app, my guess is that you're using the wrong context to get the manager, it should be the `Activity`.

Comment: Might be, I am using Calligraphy, which wraps Context. I'll try unwrapping it

Comment: Ok, let me know if it works. FYI, the `AutofillManager.getClientLocked() changed from [https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/oreo-release/core/java/android/view/autofill/AutofillManager.java#763](8.0) to [8.1](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/oreo-mr1-release/core/java/android/view/autofill/AutofillManager.java#939).

Comment: Sorry, here's the right links:
[8.0](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/oreo-release/core/java/android/view/autofill/AutofillManager.java#763) - [8.1](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/oreo-mr1-release/core/java/android/view/autofill/AutofillManager.java#939).

Comment: No, unfortunately, that is not the case, I already get AutofillManager from Activity class or its descendant

Comment: Well, I'm out of ideas then :-(

Can you reproduce the issue forking with the sample apps from https://github.com/googlesamples/android-AutofillFramework ?

Comment: I haven't been able to reproduce the issue in a different app so far. I'll try

Answer (score 0):

You might need to Configure an autofill service and you need to add view data binding logic in the onProvideAutofillStructure method.

```
<!--
Declare AutofillService implementation; only needed for a small number of apps that will
be implementing an AutofillService. Framework parses meta-data and sets the service's
Settings Activity based on what the meta-data resource points to.
-->
    <service
        android:name=".MyAutofillService"
        android:label="Multi-Dataset Autofill Service"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_AUTOFILL_SERVICE">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.autofill"
            android:resource="@xml/multidataset_service" />

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.service.autofill.AutofillService" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Comment: Isn't that for the apps that provide Autofill functionality, such as password managers (Samsung Pass, for example)? If so, that is not my case

Comment: +loredan13 is right, the autofill service is only need for apps such as password managers. As a "regular" app developer, there are some APIs you could use to optimize our app for autofill although `onProvideAutofillStructure()` is a extreme case - see https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/autofill-optimize for the common cases.